# Best way to store complex Swift objects that allows them to be extracted & shipped with app

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, realm, persistent-storage

I'm nearing the end of development of a music-making app, and I want to add the ability to save and load projects/sessions. The app is built around a 'loop machine' that stores recorded notes in multidimensional arrays, and it has many effect parameters and other states that must be saved alongside these arrays. This will be my first time working with data storage in iOS, so I'm looking for some guidance on which system might be best.

I had a look at CoreData and it seems that it would take a very long time to get this data into a suitable form for managed objects. Realm seems like an easier option, as you can save objects 'as is', right? This leads me onto the second part of the question: I'd like to ship some factory projects with the app - is there a way to extract the data saved using Realm (or another method) so that I can ship it with the app ready for the user to load?

Another consideration is how difficult it will be to integrate a data storage system into an existing XCode project.

Here is an extract of the loop machine object to give you an idea of why I think CoreData would be an inefficient method (there are a few other big classes like this):

```
open class LoopMachine {
   var delegate: LoopMachineDelegate!
   static let defaultTempo = 120
   static let numLoopsPerSource = 3
   static let minLoopLength = 4
   static let maxLoopLength = 32
   static let ticksPerBeat = 32
   var master: Master!
   var sources: Array<LoopSource?>!
   var activeSource = 0
   var beatsPerMeasure = 4
   var currentBeat = 1
   var currentTick = 1
   var metronome = AKMetronome()
   var metronomeOn = true
   var storedTempo: Int! // Used to store the current tempo when it is halved for easy rec mode
   var isPlaying = false
   var isRecording = false
   var countIn = true
   var countingIn = false
   let numSources = 12
   var quantization = 2 // How many ticks to quantize recorded notes to, min: 2 max: ticksPerBeat
   var quantizeNoteOnOnly = true
   var copiedLoop: Loop?
   var copiedLoopType: Int?
```

This is only my second time posting, so apologies if I've missed anything - just let me know.

Comment: Small or huge amount of data, local access only or network access, frequent CRUD operations or only one load/save per session? A lot of things take into account when deciding on persistence

Comment: What’s wrong with Codable? Built in serialization.

Comment: @matt cheers Cheers I'll have a look at that!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson relatively small, local only (but I would like to integrate google drive access later), infrequent operations but definitely more than once per session. From the answer below it sounds like I should be looking at serialization - didn't know it was a thing!

Comment: Here's some info. You cannot store random object properties 'as-is' in Realm. There are specific data types that Realm supports as listed [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#supported-types). In other words you can't store an NSTextField object in Realm but you can store a NSString. CoreData isn't actually storage, it's an object graph and persistence framework - the actual storage can be XML, SQLite etc. The object presented in the question cannot be stored in either, but some of those properties can i.e. you can't directly store Master or Loop objects in either.

Comment: oh and either one can be shipped with 'pre-packaged' data, see [Bundling Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#bundling-a-realm). I know there is an answer but it's unclear why they're suggesting codable as that won't really have any affect on storing objects for your app (as presented) in either Realm or CD (or any database). CD is a beast and highly flexible but the learning curve is pretty steep. Realm has a much shorter learning curve and you'll be storing and retrieving objects in just a few minutes. The guide is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear how much data you will have, but in general it sounds as though you should be looking at a document type persistence, rather than database/Core Data. Have 1 file per project.

Matt's Codable suggestion is a good place to start looking.

Save your factory projects as individual files and bundle them as resources in the app.

Comment: Yeah that sounds exactly like what I'm looking for thanks! I'll check it out and mark this as the answer if it is suitable.

Comment: I actually wrote a very similar sounding app. I wrote each composition out as an xml file. Not the most efficient but easy to build, and the files are readable. Separate files are easier to sync too, if that's an issue.